# Custom Error message in Lambda failed destination

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to send a custom error message to SQS failed destination in response payload in case lambda failed.
Is it possible?

Currently, the error message I'm getting is

```
"responsePayload": {
    "errorMessage": "('Snowflake Failed', 002003 (02000): SQL compilation error:\nFile format 'RPT_DATAPIPELINE_CONSUMER_ORMAT' does not exist or not authorized.)",
    "errorType": "Exception",
    "stackTrace": [
      [
        "/var/task/s3tolz_load.py",
        74,
        "lambda_handler",
        "raise Exception(\"Snowflake Failed\", e)"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You have a SQL message, but unclear where that message is being generated from.

Comment: Nope, I was doing negative testing, Was not able to send customer error message. But found the way now.